# Gap Between <ul> and <div> in IE7

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble diagnosing what is causing a gap in a section of my page.  I searched SO and Google, however I could not pinpoint any helpful articles.  I have a container which contains a title, an unordered list and a div with information.  The problem is a gap is occurring between the div and the ul.  I would like the div to be directly under the ul with no spaces.  An example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/aAfU5/1/ (Remember IE7)

HTML

```
<div id="center-panel">
  <h1>Information</h1>
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="bg1 border2">Regulation</li>
      <li class="bg1 border2">Compliance</li>
      <li class="bg1 border2">Resources</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="information-panel" class="border2">
      This is where the content goes
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #center-panel {
        height: 300px;
        float: left;
        width: 78%;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #center-panel ul {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #center-panel li {
        color: white;
        /*display:inline-block;*/
        /*display:inline;*/
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px 2px;
        padding: 3px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    #information-panel {
        clear: both;
        margin: 0px 2px;
    }

    h1 {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 120%;
        color: #01305E;
    }

    .bg1 {
        background: #3C698E;
    }

    .border2 {
        border: 1px solid #01305E;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your H1 margin that "spills" under the ul.
Replace it with a padding :

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #01305E;
}
```

You could also add zoom to trigger haslayout

```
#center-panel ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  zoom:1;
 }
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for the help I never would have figured that out.  Could you explain what you mean by spills?  I wouldn't expect that margin to be placed under the ul.

Comment: I edited my answer with another solution. It's an IE7 oddity when dealing with floats : your li are kinda ignored, so the margin on the element before "skips" them. Somebody may explain this better than me and my bad english.

Comment: That is very clear to me, there is no problem with your English.  Just to summarize and further my understanding, floating the li tags causes ie to place the margin between the div and ul.  +1 for the follow up appreciate it.

Comment: Basically, yes. For further understanding on these problems, you could check http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: this sentence in your article summarizes my problem best "In IE, a float will always “belong” to its layout container. Subsequent elements might respect the layout container, but not the float itself."